# Como preencher um select com angular usando materialize

Tags: angularjs, materialize

Estou tentando **preencher** um select com dados da minha **base** o problema é que tenho que selecionar sempre uma vez o select para que os dados carreguem. Como posso resolver esse problema?

**HTML**

```
 <form class="" name="formulario">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                <select  material-select></select>
                <label for="selectCliente">Cliente</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                <select ng-model="pedido.Hora" material-select></select>
                <label for="inputHora">Hora</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                <select ng-model="pedido.ProdutoId"
                        ng-options="prod.Id as prod.NomeProduto for prod in ListaProdutos" material-select>
                </select>
                <label for="inputProduto">Produto</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s2 m2 l2">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                <input id="inputQtd" type="number" class="validate" name="Qtd" ng-model="pedido.Qtd" min="0" max="">
                <label for="inputQtd">Qua</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s2 m2 l2">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
 </form>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("modaFeminina").controller("PedidoController", function ($scope, $http, $base64) {

    $scope.pedido = {}
    $scope.ListaProdutos = [];
    $scope.ListaCliente = [];

    $http.get("/Produto/Listar").success(function (produtos) {
        $scope.ListaProdutos = produtos;
    }).error(function () {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade eu descobri onde estava o problema e por um descuido acabei não percebendo que faltava o atributo **watch** após o **material-select** na tag select. Fazendo isso resolve o problema de carregar o select somente quando você seleciona o combo vazio.

**HTML**

```
   <form class="" name="formulario">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                <select
                        ng-controller="ListaClientes"
                        ng-model="pedido.ClienteId"
                        ng-options="value.Id as value.Nome for value in ListaCliente" material-select watch>
                    <option value="">Selecione um cliente</option>
                </select>
                <label for="selectCliente">Cliente</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("modaFeminina").controller("ListaClientes", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.ListaCliente = [];

    $http.get("/Cliente/Listar").success(function (clientes) {
        $scope.ListaCliente = clientes.ListaClientes;
    })
    .error(function () {

    });

});
```

Comment: Mas cade o watch?

Comment: O watch é um atributo passado no próprio html na tag select

Comment: Legal, nunca tinha visto, ou prestado atenção nessa maneira de declarar.

Answer (score 0):

Então amigo o select do material angular funciona no mesmo formato que o normal Como angular material é uma directve você tem que usar como elemento e não como atributos na sua tag html

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="someModel" placeholder="Select a state">
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in neighborhoods2">{{ opt }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

link para maiores informações

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Comment: é desaconselhado usar ng-repeat para select de acordo com a documentação do angular, o correto seria ng-option.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está usando `GET` para pegar de uma API **precisa** montar ele com jQuery, tenho trabalhado com Materialize e para fazer isso dinâmicamente ele é *bugado*, já tive que fazer "no braço" em mais de um projeto.

O html é simples:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select name="select_produto" id="select_produto">
  </select>
</div>
```

Já no temos `controller` que montar o select usando jQuery:

```
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    produto = response.data;
    var produtoSelect = $('select#select_produto');

    produtoSelect.html('<option value="-1" disabled selected>Select the product</option>');


    for (var i = 0; i < produto.length; i++) {
      var tempItem = $('<option data-icon='+produto[i].img+' class="circle" value="'+produto[i].id+'">'+produto[i].name+' </option>');
      produtoSelect.append(tempItem);
    }

    $('select#select_produto').material_select();        

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("Error for get objects!");
  });
```

Lembrando que muitas vezes as pessoas simplesmente se esquecem inicializar o select com:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
```

Então certifique-se que seu problema não é apenas isso antes de trocar a estrutura.

---

Não que seja relativo a pergunta, mas recomendo usar `.then` e trabalhar com promessas ao invés de `.success` e `.error` que está sendo descontinuado para o `angularJS`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.